# Git, a reset commit is still in local history

Tags: git

I check DEV branch from server and made a commit and then I reset with '--hard' it because I should not modify anything at this branch, I do not push to server. 
Then I search some changes with 'git log', I see my commit is still in it. Even I delete dev branch local DEV then pull again.
Actually I am sure my commit is not in DEV of server side, but it did exist in history of local DEV.

--updated--
I am sure my code is not in local DEV or remote DEV, but I can see the that log/commit with 'git log' in local DEV.
Why a reset commit be still in history of local history? Do that make sense?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: so what actually is your problem?

Comment: I think that should not in the history.

Comment: Did you do git reset --hard HEAD^ ?

Comment: Yes. My code is not int DEV, but can see the commit/log with 'git log'.